# How to exclude a subfolder from an FTP download when using WinSCP in a batch file that has spaces?

Tags: ftp, winscp

I am using a `get` function via WinSCP script to download new files from an FTP server but need to exclude a folder that has spaces. This is what I have but it's throwing an error:

```
get -filemask=|/Images/DO NOT USE/ -neweronly -resumesupport=on -resume "/FTP_FILES" "D:\FTP_Downloads"
```

Error:

```
Can't get attributes of file "NOT'.
Could not retrieve file information 
/NOT can't be listed
```

My guess is it's hanging on the fact that `DO NOT USE` folder has spaces. Unfortunately I have no access to rename this folder, and just simply want to ignore it when downloading. I tried adding quotations, didn't do anything, folder still was downloading.

How do I execute this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrap the file mask to [double quotes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#quotes), the way you already wrap the source and target paths.
2. The [path mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#path) must match a complete path. You can solve that by prefixing the path with `*` or by using an absolute path.

```
-filemask="|*/Images/DO NOT USE/"
```